# Showing the adjoint of $A = A^{-3}$ iff $A^* = A$ and $A^2 = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to show that $A^* = A^{-3}$ iff $A^* = A$ and $A^2 = I$ given $A$ is invertible and $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ but I'm having trouble with manipulating $A$ and just don't know what's legal or not. $A^*$ here is the adjoint of $A$. Any help would be appreciated!

I believe it's possible to do just by algebraic manipulation on $A$, but super lost as to how to achieve it.

Just to be super clear. $A^*$, the adjoint of $A$ is the transpose of the conjugate of $A$.

Comment: Do you mean the [Adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) with $A^*$? Usually, $A=A^*$ says that $A$ is normal, and $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose. So then just $A=A^{-3}$? Please clarify the assumptions.

Comment: Yes $A^*$ here refers to the transpose of the conjugate of $A$. Sorry if the notation wasn't clear

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ part is so trivial, because if $A^*=A\ \wedge\ A^2=I$ , then $A^{-3}=IIA^{-3}$.  So... the question is prooving $\Rightarrow$ part.

Comment: Yes agreed, the backwards direction I have shown. I have a solution for the forward direction, but the solution uses unclear/perhaps illegal matrix algebra, so I'm not confident in it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A^* = A^{-3}$ then $A^*A = AA^*$ ($A$ is normal), so by the Spectral Theorem, $A$ is diagonalizable. Do a change of basis so that $A$ is diagonal. And now you can check that the only complex numbers that satisfy $\bar\lambda = \lambda^{-3}$ are $\lambda = \pm 1$.

If $A$ is diagonal and the diagonal entries are $\pm 1$ then $A^* = A$ and $A^2 = I$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^\ast=A^{-3}$, we see that $A^\ast$ commutes with $A$. Hence $A^2=(A^\ast A)^{-1}$ is self-adjoint and positive definite. It follows that $A^2=(A^2)^\ast=(A^\ast)^2=(A^{-3})^2$, meaning that $A^8=I$ or
$$
(A^2-I)(A^2+I)(A^4+I)=0.\tag{1}
$$
Since $A^2$ is positive definite, so are $A^2+I$ and $A^4+I$. Therefore $(1)$ implies that $A^2-I=0$. But then we also have $AA^\ast-I=0$ because $A^\ast=A^{-3}=(A^2)^{-1}A^{-1}=A^{-1}$. Hence $A=A^\ast$.